# How to add text-based legend to D3.js chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts, data-visualization

I was just wondering how to add a box with text in it to my D3.js chart. It will be acting as my legend, and will describe each variable on my x-axis. It should look something like this [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi0FE.png) .

I would like to match each of the "wuc" labels to the "nomenclature" labels in this json array:

```
 data = [{
            "Wuc": "23A",
            "Nomenclature": "Engine, Basic (F117-PW)",
            "Hours": 155899.90
          },
          {
            "Wuc": "23V",
            "Nomenclature": "F‌​an Thrust Reverser",
            "Hours": 56576
          }
        ]
```

The bottom code is for my D3.js chart. Thanks for the help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <style>
    .bars:hover {
      fill: blue;
    }

    .legend:hover {
      fill: blue;
    }
    /* tooltip for bar chart */

    div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 50px;
      height: 60px;
      padding: 2px;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      background: lightsteelblue;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="bar_chart">
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //  d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
    //  if (error) throw error;
    // var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%M:%S");
    // var timeformat = d3.timeFormat("%M:%S")

    data = [{
        "Wuc": "23A",
        "Nomenclature": "Engine, Basic (F117-PW)",
        "Hours": 155899.90
      },
      {
        "Wuc": "23V",
        "Nomenclature": "F‌​an Thrust Reverser",
        "Hours": 56576
      }
    ]

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      // d.atime = parseTime(d.atime);
      d.Hours = +d.Hours;
    });
    var margin = {
        top: 70,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 80
      },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    //Define the div for the tooltip
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.Wuc
      }))
      .range([0, width])
      .padding([0.8]); //sets decimal of the space between bar centres
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.Hours
      })])
      .range([height, 0]);
    var svg = d3.select("#bar_chart")
      .data(data)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    // text label for the x axis
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width / 2)
      .attr("y", margin.top + height)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text("x-Axis Title");
    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(5));
    // text label for the y axis
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "blah")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("x", 0 - height / 2)
      .attr("y", -50)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text("y-Axis Title");
    // graph main title
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width / 2)
      .attr("y", -20)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("font-size", "20px")
      .text("Main Title");
    //********* Bar Chart ****************
    var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(data)
      .enter();
    rects.append('rect')
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i, node) { //this is repeated should be in a function
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .85);
        div.html("<strong> Name:</strong> " + d.Wuc + "</br><strong> Value:</strong> " + d.Hours)
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", "blue");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
        d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", "lightblue");
      })
      .attr("class", "bars") //should fill blue on mouseover, not working???
      .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return x(d.Wuc);
      })
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return y(d.Hours);
      })
      .attr('height', function(d, i) {
        return height - y(d.Hours)
      })
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .style('fill', 'lightblue')
      .style('stroke', 'lightgray');
    // }); //closes function d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {.....
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply append a 'rect' to the svg and also append text with data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <style>
    .bars:hover {
      fill: blue;
    }

    .legend:hover {
      fill: lightblue;
    }
    /* tooltip for bar chart */

    div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 50px;
      height: 60px;
      padding: 2px;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      background: lightsteelblue;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="bar_chart">
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //  d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
    //  if (error) throw error;
    // var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%M:%S");
    // var timeformat = d3.timeFormat("%M:%S")

    data = [{
        "Wuc": "23A",
        "Nomenclature": "Engine, Basic (F117-PW)",
        "Hours": 155899.90
      },
      {
        "Wuc": "23V",
        "Nomenclature": "F‌​an Thrust Reverser",
        "Hours": 56576
      }
    ]

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      // d.atime = parseTime(d.atime);
      d.Hours = +d.Hours;
    });
    var margin = {
        top: 70,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 80
      },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    //Define the div for the tooltip
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.Wuc
      }))
      .range([0, width])
      .padding([0.8]); //sets decimal of the space between bar centres
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.Hours
      })])
      .range([height, 0]);
    var svg = d3.select("#bar_chart")
      .data(data)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    // text label for the x axis
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width / 2)
      .attr("y", margin.top + height)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text("x-Axis Title");
    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(5));
    // text label for the y axis
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "blah")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("x", 0 - height / 2)
      .attr("y", -50)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text("y-Axis Title");
    // graph main title
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width / 2)
      .attr("y", -20)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("font-size", "20px")
      .text("Main Title");

    //************* Legend ***************

    // add legend rect gray
    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("x", 280)
      .attr("y", 30)
      .attr("rx", "5px")
      .attr("width", 230)
      .attr("height", 80)
      .attr("stroke", "darkgray")
      .attr("fill", "white");

    var legend_text = svg.selectAll("legend_text")
      .data(data)
      .enter();

    legend_text.append("text")
      .attr("class", "legend_text")
      .attr("x", 290)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 40;
      })
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.Wuc + " " + d.Nomenclature;
      });

    //********* Bar Chart ****************
    var rects = svg.selectAll(".bars")
      .data(data)
      .enter();
    rects.append('rect')
      .attr("class", "bars")
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i, node) { //this is repeated should be in a function
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .85);
        div.html("<strong> Name:</strong> " + d.Wuc + "</br><strong> Value:</strong> " + d.Hours)
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", "blue");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
        d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", "lightblue");
      })
      .attr("class", "bars") //should fill blue on mouseover, not working???
      .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return x(d.Wuc);
      })
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return y(d.Hours);
      })
      .attr('height', function(d, i) {
        return height - y(d.Hours)
      })
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .style('fill', 'lightblue')
      .style('stroke', 'lightgray');
    // }); //closes function d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {.....
  </script>
```

You may also want to make the height of the rect dynamic to fit different amounts of of data.